# laravel8 input typeahead autocomplete wont work when include @extends('layouts.app')

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, typeahead

I have been finding ways to get this work but no luck.
i want to use typeahead autocomplete function.

main scripts on my app.blade

```
 <!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>


 <!-- import JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
{{--    <script src="https://unpkg.com/element-plus/lib/index.full.js"></script>--}}
```

then i have this script on my search blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <input class="typeahead form-control"   name="query" type="search" placeholder="search" autocomplete="off"> </input>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
            return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

and then my search controller

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{

    $search_text = $request->input('query');

    $data = Skills::select("name")
        ->where("name","LIKE","%{$search_text}%")
        ->get();

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

all of these were done based on a tutorial all it works only when i remove the @extends('layouts.app') , line, or if i remove the "defer" in  on app.blade file.

but when i do that all of my style layout is getting messed up. and is there a solution for this without removing existing code. because all existing codes are important.

Answer (score 0):

try this in script
`$('input.typeahead:search').typeahead({`

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: search
Providing this error.